# Wordpress - query_posts

Tags: wordpress, loops

Is there a way to query multiple specific posts? For example, the following gets one:

```
        // retrieve one post with an ID of 670
        query_posts('p=670');
```

But as far as I can tell, I can't extend this to do two posts, separated by commas. Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
query_posts(array('post__in' => array(670, 671, 672)));
```

Source:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I will approve once time limit is up.